# xamarin forms audio recording and upload to a server

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, cross-platform, xamarin.forms.labs

Is there any possible way to record an audio and upload to a server using xamarin forms.
The best result I got after searching was this 
https://github.com/HoussemDellai/UploadFileToServer

The library used in the solution supports only Image and Video.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any possible way to record an audio and upload to a server using xamarin forms.

There are many ways realizing this feature. For recording an audio within Xamarin.Forms, you could use [`Plugin.AudioRecorder`](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder#properties-and-settings) to realize. Fore more you could refer the following code.

```
private AudioRecorderService _recoder;
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    _recoder = new AudioRecorderService
    {
        StopRecordingOnSilence = true,
        StopRecordingAfterTimeout = true,
        AudioSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)

    };
    _recoder.AudioInputReceived += _recoder_AudioInputReceived;
}

private void _recoder_AudioInputReceived(object sender, string e)
{
// do some stuff
}

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await RecodAudio();
}
private async Task RecodAudio()
{
    try
    {
        if (!_recoder.IsRecording)
        {
            await _recoder.StartRecording();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async void StopButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_recoder.IsRecording)
    {
        await _recoder.StopRecording();
    }
}
```

For uploading file, you could use the [`UploadFileToServer`](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/UploadFileToServer) that mentioned in your case. And you will get the audio file path in the `AudioInputReceived` event args.

```
private void _recoder_AudioInputReceived(object sender, string e)
{
    var path = e;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.Will try this and let you know if I succeed.I am new in Xamarin world and It would be nice if I can get your personal skypeId or email id.
Thanks again for responding

Comment: If you have any update, please feel free to post here or create another thread if the question not related with this topic. And I will try my best to assist you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Ok I have created another thread can you please take a look by following the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052724/xamarin-forms-calendar-view-yearly-monthly-and-weekly-to-show-reminder

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i got the Audio file path by above method but i am not able create MediaFile object by that audio file path, could you please help me to get a MediaFile object by providing a audio file path.

Comment: @NeeraGoel Sure, please make new thread about your problem, I will check it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Please check ..  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306057/how-to-get-mediafile-object-from-a-audio-file-path