# Xamarin forms Calendar view yearly monthly and weekly to show reminder

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Is there any calendar controls available in xamarin forms that helps to show reminders in a calendar like in the screenshots provided below.

Yearly View>

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Yycy9pDgSYbWJxaEpOblhfZ1E

Monthly View>

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Yycy9pDgSYWTVTR1BRV1VabzA

Weekly View>

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Yycy9pDgSYX21lUGpydnV0ZGM

I have tried Sfcalendar *https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfcalendar/overview*

and it has a similar view of the design but I am finding difficulty in making it showing the reminder marks on yearly view. Is there any possible way I can do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Telerik's RadCalendar](https://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/calendar) will do yearly, monthly, and weekly but I do not think it is a free product.

Comment: Hi @hvaughan3 thanks for replying. Is there any free UI component available? or any other free possibilities? 
Thanks again for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already mentioned SfCalendar control provides support to add appointments on calendar’s dates. By the way of adding collection of appointments, it will show the event with indicator on the desired dates. We can use the indicator as remainder in the monthview and it has no support in the year view. In future this support may be added. The SfCalendar control has no week view. So we can use SfSchedule control, in which Week view support is available with other built in views (Day, Work Week and Month). As of now, reminder support is not available in the control. You can know more about SFSchedule control and SFCalendar control refer the below online user guide documentation.

SfChedule:https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfschedule/getting-started

SfCalendar: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfcalendar/overview

Answer (score 0):

Like @hvaughan3 said Telerik Calendar will help you achieve this, an important note to this is that the calendar itself is a little bit tricky to understand some functionalities like customisation but you can achieve pretty complex things like:

[image: Telerik Xamarin.Forms Calendar]

Here is the link: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/calendar/calendar-overview

Comment: Thank you for replying.
 
Are there any free UI controls available or any other possible way I can do this ?

Comment: Maybe you can achieve the same with the Sync fusion calendar.

Comment: Ya currently I am using the sfcalender but it does not have the control to mark the appointments in yearly view like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Yycy9pDgSYbWJxaEpOblhfZ1E/view