# How to get MediaFile object from a Audio File path?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have used Xamarin.Android Recorder to record a audio and i am getting recorded audio file path. Now i need to upload that audio file to Server using [this](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/UploadFileToServer).

Please help me to create MediaFile object for a recorded audio file in Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android solution will also work as i will create Dependency service to use it.

Comment: if you have the path you can just open a FileStream.  There is no need to create a MediaFile object